# Compare UIImage with partial file name of UIImage

Tags: objective-c, uiimage, comparison, logic, string-comparison

Is this possible? For example I have:

```
pin.image == [UIImage imageNamed: @"Bpin_map"]
```

but I need to check for `Apin_map` and more. Is there a way to compare `pin.image` to a `UIImage` with a name that ends in `_map`?

Comment: You want to compare the contents of the images to see if they are identical?

Comment: Yes, but there are multiple images that could be a possible match

Comment: Well if it's a bit-by-bit comparison you want, you could generate a hash for each file (and that hash can be made persistent if necessary by storing it somewhere...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am going to assume you understand already the ins and outs of comparing strings (filenames) and the real problem here is that UIImage does not have a property to contain the filename from which the data was loaded...  so:

use objc_setAssociatedObject() to store the name like this:

```
objc_setAssociatedObject(pin.image,"imageName",@"Bpin_map",OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN_NONATOMIC);
```

then you can retrieve the name again using

```
NSString* filename = (NSString*)objc_getAssociatedObject(pin.image,"imageName");

if([filename hasSuffix:@"_map"])
{
 // success!
}
```